# Azure Function JAVA Development Using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, azure, debugging, azure-functions

I am trying Azure Function With Java On **Eclipse** IDE. I am able to create a function and execute it.
**Problem is** When I am trying to execute it in debugger mode. It is not stopping at debugger break point.
Is there any specific configuration to activate debugging in Eclipse for Azure Functions?

**Scenario:**

- Created an API endpoint in Azure Function Java using Eclipse with annotation `@FunctionName("myfunc")`.
- One Breakpoint used at API endpoint Method.
- Executed in Debugger mode
- Hit API End point using POSTMAN tool.
- API is working fine.
- It should stop at breaking point. But it's not.

**TOOLS :**

- Eclipse Version: 2019-12 (*4.14.0*)
- Azure Functions Core Tools (*3.0.2245*)
- Function Runtime Version: (*3.0.13139.0*)

Please, any lead will be helpful. Ask in comment if not clear.

Thank you !

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-eclipse#debug-the-function-in-eclipse

Comment: Hey @JimXu  Thank you for the comment and reference, I was executing with 
`azure-functions:run` but now we can use `azure-functions:run -DenableDebug ` 
It's the solution.

Comment: I post my suggestion as a solution. Since it is helpful for you, could you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarize the solution as below

If you want to debug Azure function in Eclipse, we need to use maven command `azure-functions:run -DenableDebug` to run the project. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-eclipse).